# Why rdd.getNumPartitions() is triggering a job in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Why `rdd.getNumPartitions()` is triggering a job in my code below?

Please consider this code:

```
employee_df = spark.read.format('csv') \
                        .option('header', 'true') \
                            .load('/FileStore/tables/employee.csv')

print(employee_df.rdd.getNumPartitions())
```

Output:
`1`

At this stage, `employee_df.rdd.getNumPartitions()` did not trigger any job and just printed number of partitions as 1.

But if I repartition the data and run `employee_df.rdd.getNumPartitions()` again as follow:

```
employee_df = employee_df.repartition(2)
print(employee_df.rdd.getNumPartitions())
```

Output:

```
(1) Spark Jobs
Job 14 

View
(Stages: 1/1)

Stage 21 1/1 succeeded   View
2
```

I see that a job has been triggered. From what I have read, `rdd.getNumPartitions()` is not an action. Then why is it triggering a job if it's not an action? Does it have something to do with repartitioning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The task action which you were seeing is not for `getNumPartitions()` but it is for `repartition()`. The `repartition()` method in Spark triggers a full shuffle, hence you see the task.

Comment: Thanks @Janani for the reply. I understand that `repartition()` will trigger shuffle data task, but I am asking about why `getNumPartition` is trigerring a job. It is not an action and therefore should not trigger a job.

Comment: While `getNumPartitions` itself isn't an action, it can initiate minimal tasks indirectly when the underlying RDD has undergone transformations that involve shuffles, like `repartition()`. Hope this gives an answer to your question.